# .Net Mobile Middleware

Tags: .net, mobile, middleware

We are looking to implement a **mobile middleware** solution in a .NET environment. We'd like to be able to write **.NET adaptors** which go a fetch data from the backend, then pass it to the MIddleware to be sent as **JSON**.

Are there any **existing systems**, open source or commercial, that provide this Mobile Middleware infrastructure?

Comment: have you seen asp.net mvc web api?

Comment: We're hoping for a move complete Mobile Middleware solution that understands a level of security, roles and the like. A package basically. SOmething we could use to consume backend Integration DLLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MVC 4 Web API turned out to be the best option